# Splitting tensorflow graph and calculating gradient of each model

Tags: tensorflow, split, backpropagation

I tried to split graph into two graph: first part, and second part.

```
X = np.array(data.select_dtypes(['float64', 'int64']))
Y = np.array(data['survived'])

X = tf.convert_to_tensor(X)
Y = tf.convert_to_tensor(Y)
print(X.shape, Y.shape)  # (1309, 9) (1309,)


client_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
client_model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(9,)))
client_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu'))

server_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
server_model.add(tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(client_model.output.shape)))
server_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

As using the conventional approach, the gradient of each trainable matrix w.r.t loss was calculated with tf.GradientTape as follow:

```
server_out = server_model(client_model.output)
joint_model = tf.keras.models.Model(client_model.input, server_out)

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    w = joint_model.trainable_weights
    tape.watch(w)
    tape.watch(X)
    y_hat = joint_model(X)
    _loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(Y, y_hat))
    
w1, b1, w2, b2 = tape.gradient(_loss, w)
# (TensorShape([9, 2]), TensorShape([2]), TensorShape([2, 1]), TensorShape([1]))
```

I got the same shape of the gradient of the second part of the graph.

```
 with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    tape.watch(X)
    h1 = client_model(X)
    y_hat = server_model(h1)
    _loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(Y, y_hat))
w2 == tape.gradient(_loss, server_model.trainable_weights)[0]  # True True
```

However, when I split this graph and backpropagate the gradient manually, it returned the wrong gradient shape. It is impossible to inner product between dE/dH1 * dH1/dW1

```
# Client gradient

with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
    tape.watch(X)
    h1 = client_model(X)
    y_hat = server_model(h1)
    _loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(Y, y_hat))
    
    
dE_dH1 = tape.gradient(_loss, h1)
dH1_dw1 = tape.gradient(h1, client_model.trainable_variables)

print(dE_dH1.shape)  # (1309, 2)
print(dH1_dw1[0].shape)  # (9, 2)
```